# ubuntu command: fc

Tags: ubuntu

Needing to compare two text files, I naturally thought to use `fc` and then I discovered that on ubuntu it is `diff` that would be the command.  `man fc` indicates that the manual has no `fc`.

Strangely when I use 'fc' I end up in a GNU nano window and the text in the nano editor is "man fc" which is a recently issued command.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the [Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/fc.1posix.html)  it says:

> **fc - process the command history list**
>
> The  fc  utility  shall  list,  or  shall edit and re-execute, commands
>          previously entered to an interactive sh.

So that would explain why it shows you `man fc`, because you entered it before trying `fc` only.

Basically the command allows you to re-edit previously issued commands. For editing it uses your default editor, which apparently is set to `nano`.